# Want to create an array of array in nodejs(javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I want to create array of array using given record.

```
user_permission =
 [ { _id: 1,
    description: 'chairman list',
    main_module: 'admin',
    sub_module: 'admin' },
  { _id: 2,
    description: 'create chairman get method',
    main_module: 'admin',
    sub_module: 'admin' },
  { _id: 3,
    description: 'create chairman post method',
    main_module: 'admin',
    sub_module: 'admin' },
  { _id: 4,
    description: 'chairman list post',
    main_module: 'chairman',
    sub_module: 'chairman' },
  { _id: 5,
    description: 'vendor list',
    main_module: 'vendor',
    sub_module: 'vendor' },
  { _id: 6,
    description: 'vendor list post',
    main_module: 'vendor',
    sub_module: 'vendor' } ]
```

using this array i want to result this type array of array like given example

```
[ 
    [ 'admin > admin': { '1': 'chairman list' },
                       { '2': 'create chairman get method' },
                       { '3': 'create chairman post method' } 
    ],
    [ 'chairman > chairman': { '4': 'chairman list post' } 
    ],
    [ 'vendor > vendor': { '5': 'vendor list' },
                         { '6': 'vendor list post' } 
    ] 
]
```

use the foreach and get the result but i don't have create proper array

```
user_permission.forEach(function(data){
    var mainmodule = [[data.main_module]+" > "+[data.sub_module]];
    var key = data._id;
    var val = data.description;

    var elem = new Array();
    elem[mainmodule] ={};
    elem[mainmodule][key] = val;
    user_prems.push(elem);
})
```

result of foreach is below:-

```
[ 
    [ 'admin > admin': { '1': 'chairman list' } ],
    [ 'admin > admin': { '2': 'create chairman get method' } ],
    [ 'admin > admin': { '3': 'create chairman post method' } ],
    [ 'chairman > chairman': { '4': 'chairman list post' } ],
    [ 'vendor > vendor': { '5': 'vendor list' } ],
    [ 'vendor > vendor': { '6': 'vendor list post' } ] 
]
```

Comment: there is no structure like these in javascript...u need object containing array right?

Comment: `[ 'admin > admin': { '1': 'chairman list' },` Your desired output is invalid. Arrays do not have key-value pairs.

Comment: you need something like this? {'admin': [{ '1': 'chairman list' }]}

Comment: fine, but how can i create this {'admin': [{ '1': 'chairman list' }]}. please give me example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your expected output is not correct. You should have a object instead of array. and them use `reduce()` to get a object which will have keys as `admin > admin,...` and values as array which will contain objects

```js
const user_permission = [ { _id: 1, description: 'chairman list', main_module: 'admin', sub_module: 'admin' }, { _id: 2, description: 'create chairman get method', main_module: 'admin', sub_module: 'admin' }, { _id: 3, description: 'create chairman post method', main_module: 'admin', sub_module: 'admin' }, { _id: 4, description: 'chairman list post', main_module: 'chairman', sub_module: 'chairman' }, { _id: 5, description: 'vendor list', main_module: 'vendor', sub_module: 'vendor' }, { _id: 6, description: 'vendor list post', main_module: 'vendor', sub_module: 'vendor' } ]
    
const res = user_permission.reduce((ac,a) => {
  let key = `${a.main_module} > ${a.sub_module}`
  if(!ac[key]) ac[key] = [];
  ac[key].push({[a._id]:a.description})
  return ac;


},{})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to transform your data:

```js
let user_permission =  [ 
{ _id: 1, description: 'chairman list',  main_module: 'admin',  sub_module: 'admin' },
{ _id: 2, description: 'create chairman get method', main_module: 'admin', sub_module: 'admin' },
{ _id: 3, description: 'create chairman post method', main_module: 'admin', sub_module: 'admin' },
{ _id: 4, description: 'chairman list post', main_module: 'chairman', sub_module: 'chairman' },
{ _id: 5, description: 'vendor list', main_module: 'vendor', sub_module: 'vendor' },
{ _id: 6, description: 'vendor list post', main_module: 'vendor', sub_module: 'vendor' } ]


let result = user_permission.reduce((prev, current) => {
    let key = `${current.main_module} > ${current.sub_module}`;
    let group = prev.find(x => x[key]);
    if(!group){
        group = { [key]: [] };
        prev.push(group);
    }    
    group[key].push({ [current._id]: current.description });
    return prev;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```